# AngularJS with Web API is not updating the data into the database

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api

I am new to the AngularJS technology and I have created a demo application where I want to Update some data into the database. I have used MVC AngularJS using Web API.

I have below Web API function which is used to update the record.

```
public IEnumerable PutProduct(int id, TblProductList product)
        {
            product.ID = id;
            if (repository.Update(product))
            {
                return repository.GetAll();
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Where reposotory.Update(product) is the function which deals with database update operation, below is the code.

```
public bool Update(TblProductList item)
        {
            if(item == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("item");
            }

            var products = ProductDb.TblProductLists.Single(a => a.ID == item.ID);
            products.Name = item.Name;
            products.Category = item.Category;
            products.Price = item.Price;
            ProductDb.SaveChanges();

            return true;
        }
```

Also please find the below angularjs controller function to update the model into the database.

```
var app = angular.module('demoModule', []);

app.controller('demoCtrl', function ($scope, $http, ProductService) {
    $scope.ProductData = null;
$scope.update = function () {
        if ($scope.Product.Name != "" &&
       $scope.Product.Price != "" && $scope.Product.Category != "") {
            alert($scope.Product.Id + ' ' + $scope.Product.Name + ' ' + $scope.Product.Category);
            $http({
                method: 'PUT',
                url: 'api/Product/PutProduct/' + $scope.Product.Id, 
                data: $scope.Product
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                $scope.productsData = response.data;
                $scope.clear();
                alert("Product Updated Successfully !!!");
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                alert("Error : " + response.data.ExceptionDetails);
            });
        }
        else {
            alert('Please Enter All the Values !!');
        }
    };



});
```

And the controller demoCtrl is bound to the Poduct.html page as per the below code.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/AngularDemo.js"></script>

<h2>Product</h2>

<div ng-app="demoModule" id="body">

    <div ng-controller="demoCtrl">

<div>
            <div>
                <h2>Update Product</h2>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="id">Id</label>
                <input type="text" data-ng-model="Product.Id" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" data-ng-model="Product.Name" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="category">Category</label>
                <input type="text" data-ng-model="Product.Category" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="price">Price</label>
                <input type="text" data-ng-model="Product.Price" />
            </div>
            <br />
            <div>
                <button data-ng-click="update()">Update</button>
                <button data-ng-click="clear()">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Now the problem in the below is when I change the details of perticular product and I click on the Update button, it will not update the data giving me the error message as 'undefined'.

Can help me to understand where I am making a mistake.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which variable is 'undefined'? Have you found it? What do you get the correct alert message for the 'alert($scope.Product.Id + ' ' + $scope.Product.Name + ' ' + $scope.Product.Category);'?

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `$scope.Product` object first. Inside `demoCtrl` controller, insert following code:

```
$scope.Product = {
   Id : '',
   Name : '',
   Category: '' ,
   Price
};
```

However, I do not see any code that set `$scope.Product` from backend API.

Comment: Hi Zamrony,   Apologies I have $scope.Product already added in the code. Still its not working

Comment: I do not see any code that declare `$scope.Product`.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the complete code as per below.

```
var app = angular.module('demoModule', []);

app.controller('demoCtrl', function ($scope, $http, ProductService) {
    $scope.ProductData = null;

$scope.Product = {
        Id: '',
        Name: '',
        Price: '',
        Category:''
    };

    $scope.clear = function () {
        $scope.Product.Id = '';
        $scope.Product.Name = '';
        $scope.Product.Price = '';
        $scope.Product.Category = '';
    }


$scope.update = function () {
        if ($scope.Product.Name != "" &&
       $scope.Product.Price != "" && $scope.Product.Category != "") {
            alert($scope.Product.Id + ' ' + $scope.Product.Name + ' ' + $scope.Product.Category);
            $http({
                method: 'PUT',
                url: 'api/Product/PutProduct/' + $scope.Product.Id, 
                data: $scope.Product
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                $scope.productsData = response.data;
                $scope.clear();
                alert("Product Updated Successfully !!!");
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                alert("Error : " + response.data.ExceptionDetails);
            });
        }
        else {
            alert('Please Enter All the Values !!');
        }
    };



});
```